# React router displays component only on refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to create a simple react router example and have added my code below. The components gets displayed on refresh but the links doesn't seem to work. I have kept my links in 'Header.js' file and the components inside a folder called 'functional'.  Can someone help me with this, am new to this and appreciate all the help.

routes.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Component1 from './functional/component1';
import Component2 from './functional/component2';
import Component3 from './functional/component3';

import Container1 from './container/container1';

import Header from './container/header';
import history from './utils/history';

import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router';

class Routes extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <div>
                        <Header />
                            <Switch>
                                    <Route exact path = "/" component={Container1} /> 
                                    <Route path="/component1" render={() => <Component1/>} />
                                    <Route path="/component2" component={Component2} />
                                    <Route path="/component3" component={Component3} />
                            </Switch>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Routes;

header.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Header extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to='/' style={{padding: '5px'}}>
                    Home
                </Link>
                <Link to='/component1' style={{padding: '5px'}}>
                    component1
                </Link>
                <Link to='/component2' style={{padding: '5px'}}>
                    component2
                </Link>
                <Link to='/component3'style={{padding: '5px'}}>
                    component3
                </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;

App.js

import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Routes from './routes';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes />
    </div>
);
}
export default App;
```

Comment: history.js file : import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();

Comment: Can you provide code for Component1/2/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes.js, try to change following:

From:

```
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
```

To:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
```